# vee-validate errors not updated when value changes on child component

Tags: vuejs2, vee-validate, kendo-ui-vue

While selecting the value from Kendo DropDownList the value get updated to the model, but the error always remains on `errors` object of the vee-validate.

The error get removed only when the form is submitted again.

I tried to implement the similar situation in the fiddle, but the fiddle shows the actual behavior. Everything is working fine on the fiddle.

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/dh5mxfoL/3/)

But when i used the same situation on the actual project the error does not reset. I need to submit the form again to reset the error.

[image]

Value updated to model but the errors still persist!

[image]

Code used in the actual project:

**Parent Component**

```
<template>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit('form-client')" data-vv-scope="form-client" autocomplete="off">

        <row-component :model="form_fields" :data-source="dataSourceArray" :scopes="'form-client'">
        </row-component>
        Selected Value: {{form_fields}}
        <br/>
        <button type="submit" class="ui submit button">Submit</button>
    </form>


</div>

</template>

<script>
import rowcomponent from "./Child";
export default {
  components: { "row-component": rowcomponent },
  methods: {
    onSubmit(scope) {
      this.$validator.validateAll(scope).then(result => {
        if (result) {
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          alert("Form Submitted!");
          return;
        }

        alert("Correct them errors!");
      });
    }
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      form_fields: {
        type: null
      },
      dataSourceArray: [
        { text: "Small", value: "1" },
        { text: "Medium", value: "2" },
        { text: "Large", value: "3" },
        { text: "X-Large", value: "4" },
        { text: "2X-Large", value: "5" }
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

**Child Component**

```
<template>
<div>
    <label class="control-label">Drop Down</label>
    <kendo-dropdownlist v-model='model.type' data-vv-name="Type" data-vv-as="Type" :data-source="dataSource" v-validate="'required'"
        :data-text-field="'text'" :data-value-field="'value'" :option-label='"Type"' :filter="'contains'" :index="0" :auto-bind="true"
        class="form-control" :class="{'input': true, 'is-danger': `errors.has(${scopes}.Type)` }">
    </kendo-dropdownlist>
    <span class="is-danger" v-if="`errors.has(${scopes}.Type)`">{{errors.first(`${scopes}.Type`)}}</span>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  inject: ["$validator"],
  props: {
    model: {
      type: Object,
      default: {}
    },
    dataSource: {
      type: Array,
      default: []
    },
    scopes: {
      type: String,
      default: ""
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

What's could go wrong with this implementation? Any help in this situation is appreciated.

Any guidelines or references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This scenario was due to the older version of `vee-validate`, i updated my code with the new version it is working as expected.

`vee-validate: 2.1.0-beta.7`